# Error CORS cuando hago una petición con axios desde react a php

Tags: php, reactjs, axios, cors

¿Cómo están? Necesito ayuda con una duda que tengo. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de seguimiento de bugs (bug tracking system) con frontend react typescript y backend en php y mysql. Ambos hosteados por separado, el primero en github y el segundo en infinityfree. El problema principal es que cuando realizo una petición con axios desde el front me aparece el error por consola de que la petición fue bloqueada por la politica de CORS.

**Mensaje de error:**

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://bug-tracking-system-backend.42web.io/login.php' from origin 'https://pabloyamakata.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute."

Ahora agrego algunos detalles adicionales:

1. La app funciona bien en local.
2. Las peticiones axios tienen activadas las credenciales (withCredentials) porque de esa forma puedo usar sesiones en php. Si las desactivo no se mantienen las variables de sesión.
3. En el back tengo todos los headers necesarios al parecer. Los mas importantes => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://... y Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true.
4. Los endpoints los he revisado muchas veces y creo que son correctos.
5. Logré conseguir el certificado ssl para el back por lo que el protocolo es https. Aclaro esto porque no pueden hacerse peticiones desde un dominio https a uno http, según tengo entendido.

Creo que eso es todo lo que pude encontrar. Ya revisé en muchos foros y no hallo respuesta.
Si necesitan mas info por favor pregunten y con gusto les respondo.

Dejo mi github con la parte de React:
https://github.com/pabloyamakata/bug-tracking-system-frontend

Aquí debajo dejo fragmentos de código que podrían ser útiles para resolver el problema:

**Petición con axios (usando formik) desde el componente Login.tsx:**

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    },
    validationSchema: yup.object({
      username: yup.string()
      .min(3, 'Username must contain between 3 and 30 characters')
      .max(30, 'Username must contain between 3 and 30 characters')
      .required('Username is required'),
      password: yup.string()
      .min(3, 'Password must contain between 3 and 60 characters')
      .max(60, 'Password must contain between 3 and 60 characters')
      .required('Password is required')
    }),
    onSubmit: values => {
      formData.append('values', JSON.stringify(values));
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: loginURL,
        data: formData,
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then(res => {
        switch(res.data.status) {
          case true:
            navigate('/dashboard');
            break;
          case false:
            setIsUserAlreadyKnown(false);
            setTimeout(() => setIsUserAlreadyKnown(true), 10000);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

**Recibo los datos con php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('headers.php');
include('connection.php');

if($method == 'POST') {
    $userdata = json_decode($_POST['values']);

    $get_user = "SELECT id, username, password 
                 FROM users 
                 WHERE username = ? 
                 AND password = ? ";
                
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
    if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $get_user)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $userdata->username, $userdata->password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
            echo $login_status = json_encode(array('status' => true));
        } else echo $login_status = json_encode(array('status' => false));
    }

    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

**El file headers.php contiene los siguientes headers:**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://pabloyamakata.github.io'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($method == "OPTIONS") {
    die();
}
```

Les agradecería mucho si pueden ayudarme. Estoy con esto hace varios días ya.